# Trying to Find Location of FSX Aircraft Wiper Directories

Tags: windows-10, windows, flight-simulator-x

I have Flight Simulator X Steam Edition and I installed an addon Airbus A340-600. The A340-600 has a similar virtual cockpit and the same exact window panels as the default Airbus A321. The A340 also includes fully functioning wipers.

One day, I noticed that the default A321 had a wiper switch but it wasn't functional. I decided to locate the code and texture files for the wipers in the A340 aircraft folder, this way I could copy these files and make working wipers for the default A321.

I searched every file in the A340 and also searched the gauges and effects folder in the FSX directory (Located in: `C:/Users/Program Files (x86)/Steam/steamapps/common/FSX)`. I couldn't find any code files with definitions for wiper control. Could someone please tell me where to find the texture and code files for the wipers. It would be nice if someone could even tell me how to safely install wipers for the default A321.